# How to solve the recurrence A(n) = A(n-1) + n*log(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

Given the recurrence:
`A(n) = A(n-1) + n*log(n)`.
How do I find the time complexity of `A(n)`?

Comment: I cant see how this recurrence relation is terminating.

Comment: @LukaRahne: Indeed. Presumably A(1) is the first term.

Comment: @Shantanu did my answer solve your problem? Could you somehow respond? I'm open to give you more explanation if needed.

Comment: @xenteros yes it does answer my question. I have marked it as the correct answer. Thanks very much!

I understood the big-O part. How would you approach finding the tight bound (big-theta)?

Comment: @LukeRahne sorry for not making that explicit in the question. It does terminate at A(1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
A(n) = A(n-1) + nlog(n)
```

Look, your recurence says: take the previous value and add `nlogn` to it.

So... assuming that A(1) = log(1) is the first element of the sequence: `A(n) = SUM from i = 1 to n (ilog(i))`.

[image]

Why?

```
A(1) = log(1).
A(2) = log(1) + 2log(2).
A(3) = A(2) + 3log(3) = 1log(1) + 2log(2) + 3log(3).
.
.
.
A(n) = 1log(1) + 2log(2) + 3log(3) + ... + nlog(n)
```

This way of solving recursion can be always used when `F(n) - F(n-1)` is a non recursive function. In our case it's `nlogn` so it worked.

Similar rule can be used when `F(n)/F(n-1)` is a non recursive function. Then we use PI instead of SIGMA.

If I were asked to give it an upper bound I would suggest to try the following:

```
  log(n)   + log(n)   + log(n)   + log(n)   + ...
+            log(n-1) + log(n-1) + log(n-1) + ...
+                       log(n-2) + log(n-2) + ...
.
.
.
```

so

[image]

Now you have a very clear upper bound, so the [big-o](/questions/tagged/big-o) is there for free (`O(nlog(n!))`). In case you're looking for a [big-theta](/questions/tagged/big-theta) you need to struggle a bit longer.

Comment: Nope, it's not. It's a sum.

Comment: Question was what is complexity for calculating recurrence relation, not what result is.

Comment: @xenteros oh yes I see, but it should be A(n) = ½ • n(n-1) • sum_{i=1}^n{log(i)} then.

Comment: @ToxiCore if you find my answer satisfying feel free to mark it as solution

Comment: @xenteros I find it very satisfying and interesting - sadly I am not the one who asked the question elseways I already would have done that :/ but you've got an upvote!

Comment: @ToxiCore haha, suprising. Anyway, you made me to struggle a bit and build a better answer.

Comment: `O(N log N!)` is the same as `O(N^2 log N)`, via Stirling's approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @xenteros do you happen to know how the big-theta (tight bound) can be found for this recurrence? Thanks!

Comment: @Shantanu not yet

Answer (score 3):

1. Let A(0)=c. Find A(n) as a function of n and c, defined by sum.
2. How many terms are in the sum?
3. What is a minimal value of the sum? Try to find an estimation.
4. What is a maximal value of the sum? Try to find an estimation.
5. If you can estimate (3) and (4) such that they one of them is constant times bigger than other, are you done? Why?